# Long pandas logic operation

Tags: python, pandas, coding-style

Is there a better way to write this long pandas logic operation? I only listed a few examples below but actually have a lot more checks. This does the job but I feel like there might be a cleaner way to express this operation. In case if you are curious about this data, it is [NYC taxi data](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/about/trip_record_data.shtml) Any advice is appreciated.

```
mask = (df.Fare_amount >= 2.5) & \
       (df.Total_amount >= 2.5) & \
       (df.Tip_amount >= 0) & \
       (df.Tolls_amount >= 0) & \
       (df.Extra >= 0) & \
       (df.Trip_distance > 0) & \
       (df.Passenger_count.between(1, 5))

# I actually have some more checks here like these above....

new_df = df[mask].copy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better way, but one option could be to group columns with the same conditions together and use `all` on the rows to reduce the number of `&` operations used:

```
mask = (df[['Fare_amount', 'Total_amount']] >= 2.5).all(1) & \
       (df[['Tip_amount', 'Tolls_amount', 'Extra']] >= 0).all(1) & \
       (df.Trip_distance > 0) & \
       (df.Passenger_count.between(1, 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer the answer given by Psidom above, because I think this one isn't particularly "Pythonic". But I thought I'd mention it because it is an alternative approach and is occasionally useful.

DataFrames support a `query` method, to which you can pass a string representing the query. This can save a few keystrokes, but if your filter criteria change often it isn't the most flexible way:

```
df.query("Fare_amount >= 2.5 & Total_amount >= 2.5 & "
         "Tip_amount >= 0 & Tolls_amount >= 0 & Extra >= 0 & Trip_distance >= 0 & "
         "1 <= Passenger_count <= 5")
```